# Making responsive a title background div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, joomla3.0

I have a module in my joomla template and i want to add the title of it to an image.
I don't know how to make it responsive? ( my module's content is responsive  but the image title isn't).

here is my code:

```
.t3-module.module.map1-title{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(".../.../images/pages.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
     background-size:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggmbrxps/)

HTML:

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{width:100%; height:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
#one{width:100%; height:100%; background:url(http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg) left top no-repeat; background-size: 100%;}
```